# Javascript new button on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit

I'm trying to get my program to create a new button on form submit. I know I've done something wrong but don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
$("#searches").append('<button id="recent-searches">' + textbox + '</button>')
```

then later on I have:

```
$("#recent-searches").on('submit', function() {
```

I think the second part of the code is where I went wrong. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `submit` event for a button, did you mean `click` or submit event on a form?

Try

```
$("#recent-searches").on('click', function() { // if you are biding this after appending the button.
```

else

```
$(document).on('click',"#recent-searches" function() { // if you are binding this prior to appending the button to the DOM. use $("#searches").on(... if that element is available all the time in DOM.
```

if `#searches` is a form then you would do:

```
$("#searches").on('submit', function(){...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#recent-searches").on('submit', function() {
```

This is going to bind to the element matching the id `recent-searches` that event. If the element doesn't exist then jQuery will do nothing. You have to bind the event to the whole document(or to a parent which will contain that element with id `recent-searches`) and specify the ID, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#recent-changes', function() {
```

In this case I think that something like this should work:

```
$('#searches').on('click', '#recent-changes', function() {
```

Since `#recent-changes` is appended to that element.

Remember that the **`submit`** event is not going to be fired when you click that button, because it is not the submit button, you can use this code:

```
$("#searches").append('<input type="submit" id="recent-searches" value="' + textbox + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a button `#recent-searches` which will receive, among others, the event `click` when you click on it. However it won't fire `submit` events because those are just for `form` elements when an `input` element of type `submit` is clicked.

So you'd have a form, let's say:

```
<form id="searches"> ... </form>
```

Where you are appending the button, maybe this way:

```
$("#searches").append('<input type="submit" id="recent-searches">' + textbox + '</input>');
```

, and then you'd do:

```
$("#searches").on("submit", function (e) { ... });
```

Or you can also have your `button` but bind a `click` event instead like so:

```
$("#recent-searches").on("click", function (e) { ... });
```